# Логика поведения счетчика голосов для закрытия вопроса

Tags: поддержка, закрытие-вопросов, голосование

Есть [такой вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1253523/parallel-foreach) и есть он же, но до того как я отдал голос на закрытие:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В голубом прямоугольнике есть причина по которой мои предшественники захотели закрыть данный вопрос. Как можно увидеть что на момент моего посещения там уже было 5 голосов. Я получается отдал 6-й ? Дальше переходим в вопрос после закрытия:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и видим что его закрыло 5 человек. Дальше переходим на историю действий над вопросом и видим что его закрыло 4 человека:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может я что-то не так понял в логике работы данного счетчика и кол-ва голосов на закрытие вцелом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверка завершена - это голоса через очередь проверок. А голоса за закрытие можно ставит просто из-под вопроса. Получается, четверо проголосовали из очереди, а один - из вопроса.